# Why does the program to find the largest number formed using elements of an array not work?

Tags: c++, arrays, quicksort

Visit https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/largest-number/ for the question...

Now I wrote the below code to solve the question (although I used an array to store the number, will do the storing in strings part later..)-

So in this algorithm, I basically used quicksort but with a twist, I changed the definition of greater than or lesser than of two numbers say X, Y such that if the number formed by using X first and Y second or XY is >= YX then greater than(X, Y) is true

In the present scenario, the code is giving runtime error, which I can't understand why, also after a bit of debugging as shown in the comments, still the answer is not coming as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std ;

bool greaterthan(int a,int b)
{
    int n1,n2,s1,s2;

    n1=((int )log10(a))+1;
    n2=((int)log10(b))+1;



    s1=a*((int )pow(10,n2))+b;
    s2=a + ((int )pow(10,n1))*b;

    if(s1>=s2){return true;}
    else{return false;}
}

int spartitions(vector<int >&B,int s , int e)
{
    int pivot = B[e];
    int pin =s;
    int i;

    for(i=s;i<=e;i++)  //if i change this to i<e 
    {
        if(B[pin]>=pivot)
        {swap(B[pin],B[i]);
        pin++;
        }
                       // and add swap(B[pin],B[e]);
    }
    return pin-1;           // and return pin here  then it works but not give correct output
}


int prand(vector<int >&B,int s ,int e)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int n = rand()%(e-s+1)+s;
    swap(B[n],B[e]);
    int pin = spartitions(B,s,e);
    return pin;
}








void qsort(vector<int >&B,int s, int e )
{
 if(s<e){
 int p= prand(B,s,e);
 qsort(B,s,p-1);
 qsort(B,p+1,e);

 }
}

vector<int> largestnumber(vector<int >&A)
{
    int n =A.size();
    vector<int >B(n);
    B=A;

    qsort(B,0,n-1);

    return B;

}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    vector<int>A(n);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>A[i];
    }

  vector<int >B(n);

  B=largestnumber(A);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
      cout<<B[i];
  }


}
```

Please Help as I am a newbie in programming and can't figure this out from like 3-4 hours ...??

Would really appreciate if someone can correct my code only and not give a different algorithm, as I want this algorithm to be corrected.

Comment: What have you been using to aid your debugging?

Comment: Just fyi, this: `srand(time(NULL));` should be in `main`, not in `prand`. Unless you're specifically looking for a repeatable pseudo-random sequence (and fyi,you're *not*) you seed it *once* per process.

Comment: @user4581301    nothing basically, just taking an example array and working through the code myself manually

Comment: @WhozCraig can you explain what you said  a bit in simpler language

Comment: @AyushMangal Don't seed the library pseudo-random generator more than once during the *entire* run if your program. The best place to do that is at/near the beginning of `main()`, *and nowhere else*.  The call to `srand` should not be in a repeated call funciton like `prand`. Take it out and move it to the beginning of `main()`. [See here for an example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/random/srand).

Comment: Most environments come with debugging software you can use to help. For example a debugger will stop dead at the crash site, allowing you to inspect the area around it and gather information. It won't help much in this case though, you've unfortunately mixed C and C++. [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) has no idea what to do with a `vector` and the old C magic used to allow it to handle arrays of different types prevents it from being able to warn you.. Consider using [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as a replacement.

Comment: I don't know if the above will solve all of your problems, but it should help you get a step or two closer,

Comment: There is a reasonable chance of integer overflow of `s1` and `s2` in `greaterthan`.  As this is a test question the test data might be chosen to guarantee this.

Comment: @WhozCraig -- Thanks, I suppose that as the computer would perform many operations in a second, if I seed every time then, for all those operations the value of rand will come same, which can be avoided if I use seed just once

Comment: @RichardCritten - Yes I was aware of that , but still I don't understand why the algorithm is not working for small digits

Comment: @user4581301 -- I just used qsort as a name  for a function , I didn't mean to use the C function

Comment: I see that. My mistake. That's a bust, so instead we're back to the debugger. Giving it a run, it looks like me' is on to something with their answer.

Comment: @AyushMangal You really should use strings.  Using floating point functions such as `log` and `pow` does not guarantee exact answers.

Comment: Why are you writing your own sort?  Just use `std::sort`, i.e. `std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), greaterthan);`.  None of this qsort / partition code.  Basically this reduces the program to 3 or 4 lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your self-written `qsort` function recursively calls itself, which adds more things to the stack, which only has so much space. When the list is too big, there will be too many function calls in the stack and it overflows. That's why anything less than 5 for the first input (which is for `n`) works fine but as soon as you exceed that, you get a runtime error. Consider not using a recursive function call.

**Edit:** **Enabling optimisation also seems to fix this issue.
This may not work depending on the compiler and how it optimises. (Works on MSVC)**

Comment: the crash is hit and miss, but such is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I seem to crash consistantly with optimisation off and `n` >= 5.

Comment: When it crashes, it sure looks like uncontrolled recursion. The trick is figuring out why the recursion wasn't controlled or why whatever happened looked like uncontrolled recursion. I'm going to push running the program through a debugger and gathering information again.

Comment: For me, the debugger just says stackoverflow and shows hundreds of calls to the sort function. So it’s probably uncontrolled recursion.